# Display the user's username when displaying their row from a seperate database table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

On my website, I have a page where I display all my user's profiles (containing info such as bio, location etc). This data is NOT stored in my 'User Model' but in a model named 'Profile'. Obviously, I display this information like this:

views.py

```
queryset_list = Profile.objects.all()
```

template

```
{% for Profile in queryset_list %}

{{Profile.bio}}

{% endfor %}
```

I also want to display these user's 'usernames' (which is stored in the User Model, NOT the Profile Model) but I don't know how to reference the User Model in relation to the Profile Model to get the connected username.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you update your question with `Profile` model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have your Profile model have OneToOne relation with User model and your Profile model look something like this

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    Male = 'Male'
    Female = 'Female'
    Other = 'Other'
    GENDER = (
        (Male, 'Male'),
        (Female, 'Female'),
        (Other, 'Other'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, choices=GENDER)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar_location', null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

where user filed is a one-to-one relation with User model, you can access detail from User model like

```
#views.py
queryset_list = Profile.objects.all().select_related('user')
```

and in your template

```
{% for Profile in queryset_list %}
    {{Profile.user.username}}
    {{Profile.bio}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: happy to help :)